# Getting rid of JQuery DatePicker in a Selenium test

Tags: python, jquery-ui, testing, selenium, selenium-rc

I am writing a Selenium test to populate a date field on a webpage. The field is associated with a JQuery Date Picker. When I use the 'type' function to enter the date, the picker pops up. However, I cannot get it to go away, even if I shift focus, click on another field etc. I've tried the following till now...

```
# Python Code
# Setting the date in the field
sel.focus('tradeDate')
sel.type('tradeDate', '8/16/2011')

# Trying to get rid of the date picker popup, none of these work
sel.key_press('tradeDate', '5')          # Trying to TAB out
sel.focus('link=[Search Filters]')       # Trying to set focus to something else
sel.focus('searchDirectory')             # Trying to set focus to another text field
sel.fire_event('tradeDate', 'blur')
sel.click('//span[@onclick="toggleTradeDetails(\'14859\',this);"]')
```

None of the above seem to work. *I am not actually trying to test JQuery. The 'tradeDate' field has its own onClick event define, which is what I am actually trying to test.*

Thus, how can I get rid of the date picker pop-up. I'm using Selenium RC against IE 8

Comment: In case it helps ... a work around we've used is to just have selenium click a certain day of the month on the date picker `sel.click("id_date")
sel.click("link=8")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using the mouseMove, mouseDown & mouseUp selenium commands to move to a different field on the page, which gets rid of the date picker

Answer (score 0):

i guess,

you don't need to use sle.focus() function as you are using sel.type() and it supplied with

element id.so it knows where to type the value. i think sel.focus() is causing the date field to pop-up the jquery date picker earlier.

if this is not solved please post the HTML code to see where exactly that Jquery date picker is attached to the text box.